# Test set creation for a rare category classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, rare-events, semi-supervised-learning

I want to make a classifier for a very rare category. The base rate in a random sample is about 0.01%, estimated from finding about 10 positive examples using a zero-shot classifier on 100,000 unlabelled examples.

I have access to a lot more unlabelled examples.

Obviously there are a lot of weird and wonderful techniques for dealing with *training* a classifier in this situation (active learning, for example), but I still need to be able to evaluate different classifiers.

I would like a hold-out/test set to *evaluate* how well I'm doing across different techniques.

**What are the options/best practice here?** Assuming it isn't practical to manually label a random sample of data to use a test set, because to get even just 100 positive examples I'd need to label 1 million examples.

Comment: Learning with a mix of labeled and unlabelled examples is [tag:semi-supervised-learning]. You might peruse that tag! If you that way get some classifier, you could manually label a fex examples that classifier gives the rare class